# RESTful web service is not starting in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have written a simple RESTful web service in JAVA but when I run it using **Run As --> Run on server** option from Eclipse IDE, I am getting `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found` error. Please tell what can be the issue in my code?

**Response:**
[image: click here see the image showing server response]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>RESTfulWebServiceExample</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**FeetToInchAndInchToFeetConversionService.java**

```
package org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.webservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("ConversionService")
public class FeetToInchAndInchToFeetConversionService {
     @GET
     @Path("/InchToFeet/{i}")
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String convertInchToFeet(@PathParam("i") int i) {

        int inch=i;
        double feet = 0;
        feet =(double) inch/12;

        return ""
        + "" + inch + ""
          + "" + feet + ""
         + "";
      }

      @Path("/FeetToInch/{f}")
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String convertFeetToInch(@PathParam("f") int f) {
       int inch=0;
          int feet = f;
          inch = 12*feet;

          return ""
            + "" + feet + ""
            + "" + inch + ""
            + "";
      }
}
```

Comment: If the solution below provided the answer to your problem, can you please select it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to go to `localhost:8080/RESTfulWebServiceExample` when, according to your `web.xml`, **RESTfulWebServiceExample** is your display name.  You need to go to `localhost:8080/rest/` to hit your servlet context root (as defined in your servlet-mapping section of the `web.xml`).